# Superpowered NDK Android: returning int succeeds in "extern" block, fails in called function

Tags: java, android, c++, android-ndk, superpowered

I'm trying to figure out how to return an int to Java from a C++ function.

On the Java side, I have the following in a button. I put it in a button to ensure that the app was completely loaded before attempting to execute returnInt().

```
int testInt;
testInt = returnInt();
Log.i(TAG, "testInt");
Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(testInt));
```

And

```
private native int returnInt();
```

On the C++ side, returning an int in an `extern` block succeeds:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint Java_com_superpowered_crossexample_MainActivity_returnInt(JNIEnv * __unused javaEnvironment, jobject __unused obj) {
    return 50;
}
```

But trying the following fails with a `SIGILL`:

```
jint SuperpoweredExample::returnInt() {
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "CrossExample ", "returnInt");  // this runs
    return 50;  // This fails with SIGILL
}

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint Java_com_superpowered_crossexample_MainActivity_returnInt(JNIEnv * __unused javaEnvironment, jobject __unused obj) {
 // fails with SIGILL
    example->returnInt();
}
```

Any idea why the above would produce a `SIGILL`?

I'm testing with a clone of the CrossExample project provided by Superpowered. (I just used CrossExample as an easy way to have a functioning Superpowered project to play with.)

My project is here:

https://github.com/mhurwicz/myCrossExample

This attempt to return an int is in the `myCrossExample1` branch of my project.

If for any reason you wanted it, the original Superpowered project is here:

https://github.com/superpoweredSDK/Low-Latency-Android-Audio-iOS-Audio-Engine

Here's debug output:

```
Signal = SIGILL (signal SIGILL: illegal instruction operand)
javaEnvironment = {JNIEnv * | 0xb40d9a80} 0xb40d9a80
 [0] = {JNIEnv} 
  functions = {const JNINativeInterface * | 0xb4032a40} 0xb4032a40
   [0] = {const JNINativeInterface} 
    reserved0 = {void * | 0x0} nil
    reserved1 = {void * | 0x0} nil
    reserved2 = {void * | 0x0} nil
    reserved3 = {void * | 0x0} nil
    GetVersion = {jint (*)(JNIEnv *) | 0xb3a505f5} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::GetVersion(_JNIEnv*))
    DefineClass = {jclass (*)(JNIEnv *, const char *, jobject, const jbyte *, jsize) | 0xb3a51ad0} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::DefineClass(_JNIEnv*, char const*, _jobject*, signed char const*, int))
    FindClass = {jclass (*)(JNIEnv *, const char *) | 0xb3a51f8c} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::FindClass(_JNIEnv*, char const*))
    FromReflectedMethod = {jmethodID (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject) | 0xb3a52c2f} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::FromReflectedMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*))
    FromReflectedField = {jfieldID (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject) | 0xb3a531b4} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::FromReflectedField(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*))
    ToReflectedMethod = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, jmethodID, jboolean) | 0xb3a536f0} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::ToReflectedMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, unsigned char))
    GetSuperclass = {jclass (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass) | 0xb3a523d8} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::GetSuperclass(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*))
    IsAssignableFrom = {jboolean (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, jclass) | 0xb3a527f0} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::IsAssignableFrom(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jclass*))
    ToReflectedField = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, jfieldID, jboolean) | 0xb3a53b50} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::ToReflectedField(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jfieldID*, unsigned char))
    Throw = {jint (*)(JNIEnv *, jthrowable) | 0xb3a53fb0} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::Throw(_JNIEnv*, _jthrowable*))
    ThrowNew = {jint (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, const char *) | 0xb3a544c0} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::ThrowNew(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*))
    ExceptionOccurred = {jthrowable (*)(JNIEnv *) | 0xb3a549da} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::ExceptionOccurred(_JNIEnv*))
    ExceptionDescribe = {void (*)(JNIEnv *) | 0xb3a54dd0} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::ExceptionDescribe(_JNIEnv*))
    ExceptionClear = {void (*)(JNIEnv *) | 0xb3a55200} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::ExceptionClear(_JNIEnv*))
    FatalError = {void (*)(JNIEnv *, const char *) | 0xb3a55a30} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::FatalError(_JNIEnv*, char const*))
    PushLocalFrame = {jint (*)(JNIEnv *, jint) | 0xb3a55e3e} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::PushLocalFrame(_JNIEnv*, int))
    PopLocalFrame = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject) | 0xb3a5625d} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::PopLocalFrame(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*))
    NewGlobalRef = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject) | 0xb3a56bd5} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::NewGlobalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*))
    DeleteGlobalRef = {void (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject) | 0xb3a572d9} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::DeleteGlobalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*))
    DeleteLocalRef = {void (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject) | 0xb3a5729f} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::DeleteLocalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*))
    IsSameObject = {jboolean (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jobject) | 0xb3a57740} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::IsSameObject(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jobject*))
    NewLocalRef = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject) | 0xb3a56b9b} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::NewLocalRef(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*))
    EnsureLocalCapacity = {jint (*)(JNIEnv *, jint) | 0xb3a57313} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::EnsureLocalCapacity(_JNIEnv*, int))
    AllocObject = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass) | 0xb3a57b90} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::AllocObject(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*))
    NewObject = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, jmethodID, ...) | 0xb3a5867c} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::NewObject(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, ...))
    NewObjectV = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, jmethodID, va_list) | 0xb3a580a5} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::NewObjectV(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, char*))
    NewObjectA = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, jmethodID, jvalue *) | 0xb3a586a7} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::NewObjectA(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*))
    GetObjectClass = {jclass (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject) | 0xb3a58c7e} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::GetObjectClass(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*))
    IsInstanceOf = {jboolean (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jclass) | 0xb3a59090} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::IsInstanceOf(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jclass*))
    GetMethodID = {jmethodID (*)(JNIEnv *, jclass, const char *, const char *) | 0xb3a599b0} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::GetMethodID(_JNIEnv*, _jclass*, char const*, char const*))
    CallObjectMethod = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, ...) | 0xb3a6a042} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallObjectMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...))
    CallObjectMethodV = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, va_list) | 0xb3a69fd9} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallObjectMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*))
    CallObjectMethodA = {jobject (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, jvalue *) | 0xb3a67197} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallObjectMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*))
    CallBooleanMethod = {jboolean (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, ...) | 0xb3a69f6f} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallBooleanMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...))
    CallBooleanMethodV = {jboolean (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, va_list) | 0xb3a69f05} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallBooleanMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*))
    CallBooleanMethodA = {jboolean (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, jvalue *) | 0xb3a6712d} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallBooleanMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*))
    CallByteMethod = {jbyte (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, ...) | 0xb3a69e9b} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallByteMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...))
    CallByteMethodV = {jbyte (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, va_list) | 0xb3a69e31} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallByteMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*))
    CallByteMethodA = {jbyte (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, jvalue *) | 0xb3a670c3} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallByteMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*))
    CallCharMethod = {jchar (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, ...) | 0xb3a69dc7} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallCharMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...))
    CallCharMethodV = {jchar (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, va_list) | 0xb3a69d5d} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallCharMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*))
    CallCharMethodA = {jchar (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, jvalue *) | 0xb3a67059} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallCharMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*))
    CallShortMethod = {jshort (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, ...) | 0xb3a69cf3} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallShortMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...))
    CallShortMethodV = {jshort (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, va_list) | 0xb3a69c89} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallShortMethodV(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, char*))
    CallShortMethodA = {jshort (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, jvalue *) | 0xb3a66fef} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallShortMethodA(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, jvalue*))
    CallIntMethod = {jint (*)(JNIEnv *, jobject, jmethodID, ...) | 0xb3a69c20} (libart.so`art::CheckJNI::CallIntMethod(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*, _jmethodID*, ...))
obj = {jobject | 0xbfcc426c} 0xbfcc426c
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call `returnInt()` before `SuperpoweredExample()`. Therefore you are dereferencing a NULL pointer, `example`.

Also you didn't return anything from the function declared as returning `jint`

You need:

```
extern "C" JNIEXPORT jint Java_com_superpowered_crossexample_MainActivity_returnInt(JNIEnv * __unused javaEnvironment, jobject __unused obj) {
    return example->returnInt();
}
```

Comment: Also have functions returning to Java return the correct Java type for clarity. It is 'jint' not 'int'.

Comment: Thanks for responding. But can the relationship of returnInt() to SuperPoweredExample() be the problem given that there are numerous other methods that are implemented just above returnInt() that are working fine?

Comment: They are called after example points to an object. Put returnInt() after SuperpoweredExample() in your Java onCreate() method.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to try to help me, Steve!  I tried putting returnInt() directly under SuperpoweredExample() on the Java side.  I also tried putting it with the code for the "Play/Pause" button, so it wouldn't be executed until the app was actually successfully running. I got a SIGILL in both cases.

Comment: Commit to GitHub.your changes please

Comment: I think it's __android_log_print now.

Comment: Thank you for sticking with me, Steve!  I added some debug output.  Is it helpful?   And all my changes are all committed.

Comment: Remember that you have to go to the myCrossExample1 branch to see the changes.

Comment: You didn't return anything from the jint returning function, see updated answer.

Comment: So simple!  Thank you very much, Steve.  I was going in circles on this for days! You have been a huge help to me.